# Eclipse key binds for navigating quick outline (Ctrl + O) - instead of arrow keys

Tags: java, eclipse, key

I'm looking to remap the keys that navigate through the quick outline <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. I cannot seem to find any keys that give this functionality. I've got <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> to go up (line up) and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to go down (line down) in the editor, but they don't work for the popup menu when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This dialog (`QuickOutlinePopupDialog`) doesn't support customization of the movement keys.

Comment: Thank you. Out of curiosity, where did you find information on 'QuickOutlinePopupDialog'?

Comment: I used [Eclipse Plugin Spy](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseCodeAccess/article.html) to find out the dialog name and then read the source code.